# C++ : When do I need a shared memory allocator for std::vector?

Tags: c++, memory, dll, stl, shared-memory

**First_Layer**

I have a win32 dll written in VC++6 service pack 6. Let's call this dll as FirstLayer. I do not have access to FirstLayer's source code but I need to call it from managed code. The problem is that FirstLayer makes heavy use of std::vector and std::string as function arguments and there is no way of marshaling these types into a C# application directly.

**Second_Layer**

The solution that I can think of is to first create another win32 dll written in VC++6 service pack 6. Let's call this dll as "SecondLayer". SecondLayer acts as a wrapper for FirstLayer. This layer contains wrapper classes for std::vector so std::vector is not exposed in all function parameters in this layer. Let's call this wrapper class for std::vector as StdVectorWrapper.

This layer does not make use of any new or delete operations to allocate or deallocate memory since this is handled by std::vector internally.

**Third_Layer**

I also created a VC++2005 class library as a wrapper for SecondLayer. This wrapper does all the dirty work of converting the unmanaged SecondLayer into managed code. Let's call this layer as "ThirdLayer".

Similar to SecondLayer, this layer does not make use of new and delete when dealing with StdVectorWrapper.

**Fourth_Layer**

To top it all, I created a C#2005 console application to call ThirdLayer. Let's call this C# console application as "FourthLayer".

**Call Sequence Summary**

FourthLayer(C#2005) -> ThirdLayer(VC++2005) -> SecondLayer(VC++6) -> FirstLayer(VC++6)

**The Problem**

I noticed that the "*System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory*" exception is being thrown which I suspect to be due to SecondLayer's internal std::vector allocating memory which is illegal for ThirdLayer to access.

This is confirmed I think because when I recompile FirstLayer (simulated) and SecondLayer in VC++2005, the problem disappears completely. However, recompiling the production version of FirstLayer is not possible as I do not have the source code.

I have heard that in order to get rid of this problem, I need to write a shared memory allocator in C++ for SecondLayer's std::vector which is found in the StdVectorWrapper class. I do not fully understand why I need a shared memory allocator and how it works? Any idea?

Is there any readily available source code for this on the internet that I can just compile and use together with my code in SecondLayer?

Note that I am unable to use the boost library for this.

Comment: Forget my first answer. It was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for the problem. Basically, the StdVectorWrapper class which I wrote do not implement deep copy. So all I need to do is to add the following to the StdVectorWrapper class to implement deep copy.

- Copy Constructor
- Assignment Operator
- Deconstructor

Edit: Alternative Solution

An even better solution would be to use [clone_ptr](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/algorithms/general/print.php/c10407__2/) for all the elements contained in std::vector as well as for std::vector itself. This eliminates the need for the copy constructor, assignment operator and deconstructor.

Answer (score 0):

Each executable or dll links to a particular version of the c runtime library, which is what contains the implementation of `new` and `delete`. If two modules have different compilers (VC2005 vs VC6) or build settings (Debug vs Release) or other settings (Multithreaded runtime vs non-multithreaded runtime), then they will link to different c runtimes. That becomes a problem if memory allocated by one runtime is freed by a different runtime.

Now, if I'm not mistaken, templates (such as std::vector or std::string) can cause this problem to sneak in where it isn't immediately obvious. The issue comes from the fact that templates are compiled into each module separately.

Example: module 1 uses a vector (thus allocating memory), then passes it as a function parameter to module 2, and then module 2 manipulates the vector causing the memory to be deallocated. In this case, the memory was allocated using module 1's runtime and deallocated using module 2's runtime. If those runtimes are different, then you have a problem.

So given all that, you have two places for potential problems. One is between FirstLayer and SecondLayer if those two modules haven't been compiled with the *exact* same settings. The other is between SecondLayer and ThirdLayer if *any* memory is allocated in one and deallocated in the other.

You could write a couple more test programs to confirm which place(s) have problems.

To test FirstLayer-SecondLayer, copy the implementation of the SecondLayer functions into a VC6 program, write just enough code to call those functions in a typical manner, and link only against FirstLayer.

If that first test doesn't fail, or else once you've fixed it, then test SecondLayer-ThirdLayer: copy the ThirdLayer implementation into a VC2005 program, write the code to make typical calls, and link against SecondLayer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at a different solution architecture.

The binary code generated by VC6 stl vector and string is, I believe, different from the code generated by more recent version of VC because of the many stl upgrades. Because of this I don't think your architecture will work as the dlls will have two implementations of std::vector and std::string that are not binary compatible.

My suggested solution is to go back to VC6 and write a new wrapper dll for FirstLayer that exposes it via a pure C API -- this layer will need to be compiled using VC6sp6 to ensure it is binary compatible with FirstLayer. Then use PInvoke in Fourth_Layer to access the VC6 wrapper DLL.